# Adding a second SQLite db in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sqlite

I have a ROR application with a sqlite3 db.
I want to create a new database, and I do not want to delete the previous one.

1. how I will define a new db in a current project, so as when I run rake db:create referring to the new one?

generally what is the process to add a new sqlite db in the existing project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

1. change database name in database.yml file
2. `rake db:create`
3. `rake db:migrate`

Comment: In the yml file there is a development: database, which I changed it, but it seems that nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

Just change database name in `database.yml` file

```
development:
  database: 'changed ndb_name'
  ...
```